# Getting Slick npm package to work with React and Meteor

Tags: meteor, npm, slick.js

I am trying to use [Slick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slick-carousel) with Meteor 1.3 and React. I added the npm package and imported the css file correctly but I can't import the js file. I then tried to import the slick module but apparently it doesn't exist. I tried `import slick from "slick";` and I got **Error: Cannot find module 'slick'**.

I checked the slick code and I don't see a `module.exports = slick`. How do I then use the Slick package in my meteor project?

Comment: `import { slick } from 'slick-carousel';`?

Comment: That did work but I get a "_jquery.$(...).slick is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues with Meteor, React and Slick Carousel.  I actually gave up on it my implementation using the npm module, but I have figured out a way to implement it into my project.

I was able to find a npm module called [React-Slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) and it integrates right into components.

After you `import Slider from 'react-slick`.
You can then add `<Slider {...settings}><div>Content</div></Slider>`